# convert string Time/Date values to dateTime value using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have to controls(date picker,time picker) , I take the values as string, and I want to set them in this object, what can I do?

Note that .Date is declared as dateTime in the table.

```
dim  DateVal As String
dim TimeVal As String

 With Object

  .Date = ???

End With
```

Comment: You are "taking" them as string, how and more important, why? If you use a `DateTimePicker` control it has a [`Value` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) that returns a `DateTime` not a string.

Comment: I am creating a reminder, the user has to to choose reminder date an time, I pass these values over a webservice method so I receive the values as string.  @Tim Schmelter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are "taking" them as string, how and more important, why? If you use a `DateTimePicker` control it has a [`Value` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) that returns a `DateTime` not a string.

So just use that property and don't convert or box the type to object and never convert it to `String` if you don't want to show it, leave it as what it is, a `DateTime` variable.

> I am creating a reminder, the user has to to choose reminder date an
>   time, I pass these values over a webservice method so I receive the
>   values as string.

Then you're asking how to convert the string to `DateTime`, use `Date.Parse` or `Date.TryParse`:

If the format is common:

```
Dim dt As Date = Date.Parse(dateString)
```

If it might be invalid:

```
Dim dt As Date
If Date.TryParse(dateString, dt) Then
    ' ....
End If
```

If the format is uncommon or not the same as the current culture(read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
Dim format = "MMM dd, yyyy" ', e.g.: Oct 02, 2013
Dim dt As Date
If Date.TryParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, dt) Then
     ' .... 
End If
```